# L'Hopital's rule application

Tags: limits, analysis

Why can't L'Hôpital's rule be used for this limit

$\lim _{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{x^{2}-x}{x^{2}-2 x+1}$

Here's the correction for the exercice:
$$
\frac{x^{2}-x}{x^{2}-2 x+1}=\frac{x(x-1)}{(x-1)^{2}}=\frac{x}{x-1}
$$
So the limit from the left is $-\infty$, and from the right is $+\infty$. We conclude that the limit does not exist.

Comment: You can! What do you get when you use L'Hopitals?

Comment: And if you use L'Hopital, you are led to consider $\frac {2x-1}{2x-2}$ and again we see that the limit does not exist.

Comment: @Lulu why exactly does that limit not exist, wouldn't it be +infinity ? (1/0)

Comment: @AlexanderTheGreat By that logic the limit you get by factoring would also go to infinity, wouldn't it? (so no, 1/0 doesn't go to infinity if you approach from both sides)

Comment: @StephenDonovan great thank you !